# Meteor, publish double join reactive

Tags: mongodb, meteor

as you see below, in my publish method I need to do a join twice, and the way I've done it throws an "Error: Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors" exception. and it is not even reactive!

is it possible to do it in a better way, I am very performance conscious and don't want to do 3 trips back and force between client and server, also some packages hit the database once for every item in an array!!

```
Meteor.publish('post', function(id) {
    Posts.incView(id);
    parentPost= Posts.findOne({_id: id});
        console.log(parentPost);

    eachPost= Posts.find({_id: {$in : parentPost.childs }});
    users=[parentPost.createdBy];
    eachPost.forEach( function(each) { users.push(each.users)});
    return [
        parentPost,
        eachPost,
        UInfo.find({_id:{$in:users}})
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findOne()` returns an object, not a cursor, which is why you're getting an error. Change findOne code to:

```
parentPost = Posts.find({_id: id});
```

This way you'll return three cursors.

Comment: I am getting "Publish function returned multiple cursors for collection posts" now, can't I send more than one cursor of the same collection???

Comment: You can't return more than one cursor for the same collection from a publish function.

Comment: Ah wasn't paying attention to the collection names, my mistake.